# Php into HTML table

Tags: php, html

Probably a very easy question but how would I insert these date values into a html table column?

```
<?php
  $startdate = strtotime("Monday");
  $enddate = strtotime ("+3 weeks", $startdate);
  while ($startdate < $enddate) {
  echo date("M d", $startdate),"<br>";
  $startdate = strtotime("+1 week", $startdate);
  }
```

Comment: And the table is? o_0

Comment: Is there specific part you don't understand how to do? You seem to understand echoing html elements, so I'm unsure what the issue is.

Comment: Look up how to make a table. Write between a `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try something like this

```
$startdate = strtotime("Monday");
$enddate = strtotime ("+3 weeks", $startdate);
echo '<table border="1">';
while ($startdate < $enddate) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.date("M d", $startdate).'</td></tr>';
    $startdate = strtotime("+1 week", $startdate);
}
echo '</table>';
```